# Compare 2 strings in R

Tags: r

I have data as below:

```
vec <- c("ABC|ADC|1","ABC|ADG|2")
```

I need to check if below substring is present or not
"ADC|DFG", it should return false for this as I need to match exact pattern.
"ABC|ADC|1|5" should return True as this is a child element for the first element in vector.
I tried using grepl but it returns true if I just pass ADC as well, any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you show an example string to match

Comment: akrun - Eg for Strings which should give TRUE are "ABC|ADC","ABC|ADC|1|2","ABC|ADG","ABC|ADG|2|5"

Comment: IceCreamToucan - For string "ABC|ADC" it should be TRUE but for "ADC|1" it should be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grepl` returns true because the pipe character `|` in regex is a special one. `a|b` means match `a` or `b`. all you need to do is escape it.

```r
frtest<-c("ABC|ADC","ABC|ADC|1|2","ABC|ADG","ABC|ADG|2|5")
# making the last number and it's pipe optional
test <- gsub('(\\|\\d)$', '(\\1)?', frtest)
# escaping all pipes 
test<-gsub('\\|' ,'\\\\\\\\|',test)
# testing if any of the strings is in vec
res <- sapply(test, function(x) any(grepl(x, vec)) )
# reassigning the names so they're readable
names(res) <-frtest
#>    ABC|ADC ABC|ADC|1|2     ABC|ADG ABC|ADG|2|5 
         TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

Comment: but then the `?` operator will be matched literally thus spoiling the expression

Answer (score 0):

For two vectors `vec` and `test`, this returns a vector which is `TRUE` if either the corresponding element of `test` is the start of one of the elements of `vec`, or one of the elements of `vec` is the start of the corresponding element of `test`.

```
vec <- c("ABC|ADC|1","ABC|ADG|2")
test <- c("ADC|DFG", "ABC|ADC|1|5", "ADC|1", "ABC|ADC")

colSums(sapply(test, startsWith, vec) | t(sapply(vec, startsWith, test))) > 0

# ADC|DFG ABC|ADC|1|5       ADC|1     ABC|ADC 
#   FALSE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE
```